# Can I find all of my open accounts?

Tags: united-states

In the USA, I have had multiple HSA custodians over the last decade and I recently discovered one I had forgotten about (because of a notification that my balance was going to be considered abandoned and subject to escheatment)

Is there a way I can find all of my active accounts, across custodians, without trying to remember them all? I imagine it's possible I have other accounts I've forgotten, but would like to consolidate.

I'm trying to avoid calling every bank I can remember and asking whether or not I have an account.

Comment: Why didn't you keep track of them?  Why did you not transfer them when they were no longer needed?  As adults, when we make mistakes it costs us money and this was clearly your responsibility to manage your accounts.

Comment: Yep. I screwed up and it cost me fees. I think I have done them all but now I'm looking to see if there are any I forgot

Comment: Not a criticism. This is a good example to members about keeping organized and keep accounts to a minimum. When my father in law died, I spent months visiting banks with his death certificate to get the account moved and retitled. By the time my Mother in law died? The one remaining acct transferred to a trust for my sister-in-law. Single transaction.

Comment: Yep. Lesson learned through participating in the challenge of closing a parent's estate so now I'm working to consolidate and document my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside: banks are not the only possible HSA custodians.

All tax-trust account custodians (IRAs, HSA, Archer, Coverdell, and the new QSA) are required to file an appropriate type of form 5498 each year, which for HSA is 5498-SA; they are also required to provide you a copy, but if you lost touch with them and didn't give or update your current address those copies may have gotten lost.

I'm *pretty* sure if you get a ['wage and income transcript'](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/transcript-types-and-ways-to-order-them) it will include all 5498's, in spite of the name. The description on the webpage only lists the basic 5498 for IRAs, but Form 4506T (which you can download as PDF, print, fill and sign, and fax or mail) describes this as "Form W-2, Form 1099 series, Form 1098 series, or Form 5498 **series** transcript." (emphasis added) According to the website this type of transcript is available through thei online app, but the authentication for that is very strict -- NTA (the IRS ombudsperson) consistently reports only about 1/3 of people pass it. (I tried a few years ago, and failed.)

Somewhat similar for IRA: [Catching up on 8606 forms for non-deductible IRA contributions](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/70462/catching-up-on-8606-forms-for-non-deductible-ira-contributions)

Comment: This worked and was very easy using the new online system!

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the IRS service mentioned in dave_thompson_085's answer, you might be able to get the information your need from your personal copies of you tax documents.

Each year you put money into the HSA, or withdrew money from the HSA should have triggered the 5498 form to you and the IRS. Even if the only thing you have is a pdf of the tax forms you submitted to the IRS, there should be enough information to get the name of the custodian. The 5498 may have even more information such as the account number.

Of course it is possible that your account was transferred to another custodian during the intervening years, and you either never received the notice, or have since disposed of it.